# Getting href by looking for another tag

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to extract href links from a web page that has multiple rows like below but I only want the a href of the ones that have the `<b>` block

```
<tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
 <td>
  <a href="?6384593.html" style="background-color: transparent;">
  <span class="ts">
    <font size="1">
     <font color="#006633">
     </font>
    </font>
    <b>Lee Swanson Research Update</b>
    <font color="#7777CC"> - Swanson Health Products</font></span>
    </a>
 </td>
</tr>
```

In this case I use the xpath expression "//b" to find the bold tag, but what I specifically want is the a href link. Is this possible with xpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//b/ancestor::a[1]/@href
```

Try something like the above

Answer (score 2):

The below **XPATH** will work :

```
//a[.//*[local-name(.)='b']]/@href
```

**UPDATE** AS @Jens Erat suggested.

```
//a[.//b]/@href
```

Comment: Why use `name(...)`? This is bad for two reasons, it will bring problems with namespaces (better use `local-name(...)` in most cases), and the expression `//a[.//b]/@href` is much more readable and shorter and does the same...